# the frame form-group exceeds the grid ReactDataGrid

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, react-data-grid

As you can see in the image attached, the frame exceeds the grid. how can I style the frame to match grid height or changing the height of the reactdatagrid to match with the height of the frame ?

Thank you

[

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div className="row clearfix">
<br/> <div className="form-group">
                      <div style={{ width: '100%'}}>
                          <ReactDataGrid
                              ref='grid'
                              rowKey='id'
                              columns={this.state.columns}
                              rowGetter={this.rowGetterM.bind(this) }
                              rowsCount={this.props.motif.motifdetail.items.length}
                              onGridSort={this.handleGridSortM.bind(this) }
                              minHeight={500}
                          />
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq5Ej.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it using
minHeight={(this.props.motif.motifretraitdetail.items.length) * 25} as 25px is the default height of each row.

[https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-height/#:~:text=Community%20for%20free.-,React%20Data%20Grid%3A%20Row%20Height,when%20using%20Viewport%20Row%20Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-height/#:%7E:text=Community%20for%20free.-,React%20Data%20Grid%3A%20Row%20Height,when%20using%20Viewport%20Row%20Model).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).